# revert a chain migration

Tags: runtime-upgrade, migration

We executed a chain migration that was not intended ( it was already executed one time and was executed again 2 times ) https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.18/frame/system/src/migrations/mod.rs#L124 is there any way to revert it back easily ?

```
/// Migrate from dual `u32` reference counting to triple `u32` reference counting.
pub fn migrate_from_dual_to_triple_ref_count<T: V2ToV3>() -> Weight {
    let mut translated: usize = 0;
    <Account<T>>::translate::<(T::Index, RefCount, RefCount, T::AccountData), _>(
        |_key, (nonce, consumers, providers, data)| {
            translated = translated + 1;
            Some(AccountInfo { nonce, consumers, providers, sufficients: 0, data })
        },
    );
    log::info!(
        target: "runtime::system",
        "Applied migration from dual to triple reference counting to {:?} elements.",
        translated
    );
    <UpgradedToTripleRefCount>::put(true);
    Weight::max_value()
}
```

Comment: If this is for development purposes, you could do a [parachain rollback](https://hackmd.io/3BAy3HEzRVO2sBFnUaBVKA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there are only 2 ways to do this.

1. publish a new version, mark that block as a bad block and resync all chains with the new client. this is a hard fork.
2. try to find out the opposite migration logic and apply it to your chain

Comment: if we do 1, will it give a problem with babe stopping working ?